# Big-O of list slicing

Tags: python, list, big-o

Say I have some Python list, `my_list` which contains N elements. Single elements may be indexed by using `my_list[i_1]`, where `i_1` is the index of the desired element. However, Python lists may also be indexed `my_list[i_1:i_2]` where a "slice" of the list from `i_1` to `i_2` is desired. What is the Big-O (worst-case) notation to slice a list of size N?

Personally, if I were coding the "slicer" I would iterate from `i_1` to `i_2`, generate a new list and return it, implying O(N), is this how Python does it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Getting a slice is O(`i_2 - i_1`).  This is because Python's internal representation of a list is an array, so you can start at `i_1` and iterate to `i_2`.

For more information, see the Python [Time Complexity wiki entry](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list)

You can also look at the implementation in the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c353764fd564e401cf47a5d9efab18c72c60014e/Objects/listobject.c#L440) if you want to.

Comment: I just need my_list[1:] but performed often, so it looks like it will double to complexity vs my_list. My lists have fixed size, the elements may change values. How expensive is to keep a reference to slice of a fixed list?

Comment: Update: I wrote a custom iterable class that iterates over my existing list, it should have no penalties.

Answer (score 42):

according to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

it is O(k) where k is the slice size

Answer (score 10):

For a list of size N, and a slice of size M, the iteration is actually only O(M), not O(N). Since M is often << N, this makes a big difference.

In fact, if you think about your explanation, you can see why. You're only iterating from i_1 to i_2, not from 0 to i_1, then I_1 to i_2.

Answer (score 0):

Its just the difference between the largest value in the slice and the lowest value in slice, you could think of it like: O(LARGEST_NUM - LOWEST_NUM) cause python only iterates from lowest to largest but you wanna get a positive number since it cant be negative. Or you could just say O( |LOWEST_NUM - LARGEST_NUM| )
where | | is the absolute value. In competitive programming, if a problem involves list slicing, there is almost always a test case where the difference is roughly O(N) so if you do CP just watch out for that.

Comment: This answer implies that the values inside the list matter to the speed of slicing, which isn't true. I'd suggest editing it to make that clear.