# Time complexity of list slicing and f-string in a loop

Tags: python, string, list, time-complexity, big-o

Given a string `word`, I'm trying to estimate the Big-O time complexity of the following function.

```
def wildcards(word: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    for j in range(len(word)):
      yield f"{word[:j]}_{word[j + 1:]}"
```

I've read [Is the time-complexity of iterative string append actually O(n^2), or O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34008010/839733) and [Time complexity of string concatenation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133547/839733), both of which are concerned with repeated string concatenation, which isn't happening here.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203617/839733) answer says slicing is linear in size of the slice, so, two slices takes `O(n)` time in total. But what about the f-string?

Overall, it looks to me that `wildcards` is O(n<sup>2</sup>), is that right?

Comment: What are the generated strings used for? Depending on the use case you may not need to actually make *n* copies of the input string but simply keep track of the incrementing index of the underscore to improve the overall time complexity to *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *O(n²)* time complexity and *O(n)* space complexity, but not because of the f-string.

You have an outer loop over the length of the string:

```
for j in range(len(word)):
    ...
```

Then, string slicing is nested inside this loop, which is also an *O(n)* copy of the string on each iteration.

Note that just `wildcards(word)` is *O(1)*, because just creating the generator doesn't do anything, so it's only *O(n²)* if you're actually consuming the generator.

Comment: What actually happens here `f"{word[:j]}_{word[j + 1:]}"`? The two slices are created (`O(n)`) and then f-string creates a new string by copying over the characters (`O(n)`)?

Comment: Yes, but 3x _O(n)_ is still _O(n)_.